How to Contribute to an Open Source PR for a New Feature?
I am an active contributor to an open-source project on GitHub, having developed a complete Portuguese (pt_BR) translation for the project. Recently, I found a PR from another contributor introducing an exciting new feature. I would like to add pt_BR translations for this feature to ensure it is fully accessible to Portuguese-speaking users upon release.
Here are the details and issues I'm facing:

Best Practices: What are the recommended best practices for adding contributions, like translations, to an existing PR in an open-source project?

Technical Steps: I need guidance on the technical steps to follow. Should I fork the branch or is there another method?

Community Etiquette: How should I approach the contributor and the community to ensure my contributions are well-received and smoothly integrated? I have already reviewed and approved the code changes in the PR, suggesting updates to the translation files.


I attempted to create a GitHub Codespace from the feature branch of the existing PR to add my translations directly. However, when I tried to synchronize my changes, I found out I didn't have the necessary permissions to push.
My current plan is to fork the project, create a branch based on the new feature's branch, update the fork, and then create a PR from my branch directly to the branch I want to contribute to. I'm looking for validation on whether this approach is viable or if there are other considerations I might be overlooking.
Any guidance or insights on these points would be greatly appreciated as I aim to continue making meaningful contributions to open source projects on GitHub.

StackOverlow is for programming-related questions, not to ask for opinions on best practices like this. This would be more suited for Open Source StackExchange.
